# CSS - How is this background achieved on this website?

Tags: css

https://www.reddbar.com/

The background scrolls and at certain points changes (as you can see when it goes from blue to green with the clouds). I'm wondering what the term is for this sort of background (I don't think parallax is correct, nor infinite scroll?)

And also, how it is achieved? Just looking for pointers in the right direction for how this effect is done.

Comment: See background css properties

Comment: [background image](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0021/7687/6644/t/25/assets/redd-bg-new_2000x.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It uses a background image.

The image is large enough (i.e. tall enough), that when you scroll down the image, you only see a bit at a time.

The different colours are contained in the image.

Other than the link to the background image, the following style properties are set inline on that div element:

```
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top
```

No linked style sheet is involved.

Here is a link to the image it uses:

https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0021/7687/6644/t/25/assets/redd-bg-new_2000x.jpg?v=16798883447530179250

This custom image has been made specifically to fit this page, keeping all the page content and layout in mind.

In this particular implementation, this background image is set inside a div element called "home-background" that is within the page body, and all of the visible elements on that page are child elements contained within this div element.

For more information see https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_background-attachment.asp

Comment: How on earth is the text/images aligned with the background? For example, a new section of text is introduced when the background changes.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_background-attachment.asp here